# How can I convert probability into score?

Tags: text, machine-learning, nltk

I am now working on a document recommendation program and I am kinda stuck here. 
For each document, I have a score assigned according to user's actions. Then, when a new document comes in, I need to predict how user will like it and rerank the whole documents again according to their scores. My solution is to use a threshold to divide those scores into "recommend" and "not recommend". Then naiveBayes or other classification models can either give me a label or return the possibility of that label (I am using NLTK package to do text analytics). 
Am I on the right way? My question is when I get that possibility, how can I convert it into the score that I use to do the ranking? Or I should use logistic regression in scikit instead?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest trying out something like the SVM-Rank algorithm.  It takes as input a set of "recommended" and "not recommended" vectors and then learns how to rank them so that the recommended ones come first.  There is also a simple python tool in dlib you can use to do it.  See here for an example: http://dlib.net/svm_rank.py.html

Comment: Hi David, the example is quite straightforward and helpful! I did some research after I saw @Raff.Edward 's answer and it seems that svm-rank is one of the solutions, but all explanations are using lots of formulas, which make a green hand like me hard to understand. The example you gave is just what I am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to force a ranking problem into a classification problem. What you really want to do is [learn how to rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank) the documents given a "query".

Comment: Thanks!I think you are right. What I am solving is a ranking problem.